# Show that as $N \to \infty$, $\sum_{i=N}^\infty{1} \to 0?$

Tags: limits

How do I show that as $N \to \infty$, that
$$\sum_{i=N}^\infty{1} \to 0?$$
Don't know how to even start. Thanks..

Apparently this is wrong. But my teacher said that if $P_n f = \sum_{j=0}^n(f,w_j)w_j$, where $w_j$ is orthonormal basis of $L^2$, then $|P_n f- f|_{L^2} \to 0$. How can that be then? Because I thought
$$|P_nf - f| = |\sum_{j=0}^n(f,w_j)w_j - \sum_{j=0}^\infty(f,w_j)w_j| = |\sum_{j={n+1}}^\infty(f,w_j)w_j| \leq \sum_{j={n+1}}^\infty|f|$$
where the last equality is by Cauchy Schwarz.

Comment: You cannot show that since it is a false statement.

Comment: Your example doesn't contradict the statement about $L^2$, since the constant function $(1,1,1,1,\ldots)$ is not in $L^2$.

Comment: @ZachL. Please see my working

Comment: @michael_faber You have an inequality $A \le B$ where $A \to 0$.  That tells you absolutely nothing about whether  or not $B \to 0$.

Comment: @ErickWong OK, I make another thread.

Comment: Why the downvote to the OP's question?

Comment: @GitGud The question is a muddled and indirect way of asking what the OP seems to be actually interested in, which is the new question.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298796/how-to-show-projection-of-l2-function-converges-to-that-l2-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit does not exist.

Consider the summation $\sum_{j=N}^{M-1} 1 = M- N$ for $M > N$. Roughly, you are after $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} M - N$.

This limit does not exist. You can reason this out formally by expanding out the meaning of a limit diverging to $\infty$.  What I have below is most likely overkill for this problem.

Roughly, $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \infty$ means that $\forall K\ \exists x_0\ \forall x \geq x_0, f(x) > K$.

In this case, you want to show that

$ (\forall\ K \geq 0)\ (\exists N_0 \geq 0)\ (\forall N \geq N_0)\ (\exists M_0 \geq 0)\ (\forall M \geq M_0),\ M - N > K$.

The statement above follows by setting $N_0$ to be some fixed number and $M_0 \geq N + K+1$.

Comment: $|P_n f - f|_{L2} \rightarrow 0$ only if $f$ is a $L_2$ function (square integrable). The function whose projection leaves an "infinite tail" of 1s is not square integrable. This follows from something like the Parseval's identity?

Comment: The last paragraph (beginning with *This limit does not exist*) is misleading. None of the cases $M=N^2$ and $M=N+c$ is relevant since one should only be concerned with the limit of $L_N$ when $N\to\infty$, where $L_N$ is the limit of $\sum\limits_N^M$ when $M\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank  you. I have made the argument entirely formal. Hope I did not mess up. :-)

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{i=N}^{+\infty}1\right)=+\infty$$

Comment: But my teacher said that if $P_n f = \sum_{j=0}^n(f,w_j)w_j$, where $w_j$ is orthonormal basis of $L^2$, then $|P_n f- f|_{L^2} \to 0$. How can that be then?

Comment: She probably mentioned "when the function is square integrable".

Comment: @michael_faber: one theorem that is used to justify the interchange of limit and sum is the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). The answer above shows that the limit fails. Suppose that 
$$
f_N(i)=\left\{
\begin{array}{}
0&\text{if }i\lt N\\
1&\text{if }i\ge N
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Why does the DCT fail to justify
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_N(i)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\lim_{N\to\infty}f_N(i)
$$
?

Answer (score 0):

When you say
$$\sum_{i=N}^\infty s_i$$
What you really have is a nice shorthand for:
$$lim_{M\to\infty} \sum_{i=N}^Ms_i$$
You can't just extend the notion of a sum, which is a combination of two elements in a group to a third, to a sum of an infinite number without some sort of limiting process. So what you're looking for is a limit that doesn't exist.